# Parameterization of a 3D intersection curve between a cylinder and a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Let $C$  be the intersection curve between cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=4$ and the plane $z =y+3$ in $R^3$

Find a parameterization of $C$ which goes in a positive direction of rotation (counter-clockwise) relative to the $xy$ plane.

what I did: we know that $x^2+y^2=4 \rightarrow (x-0)^2+(y-0)^2=2^2$ which gives us that $r=2$.

So the parameterization would be $x=2\cos(t), y=2\sin(t)$ for $t\in[0, 2\pi]$

is this correct?

Comment: What about the $z$-coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations for the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are correct since they represent the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2^2=4$.  Since the cutting curve is the intersection of this cylinder and the plane $z=y+3$, the remaining step is to write $z = y + 3 = 2\sin(t)+3$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks, got it. But If i'm going to use the line integral $\int F dr$ of a vectorfield given by $F(x,y,z)=xi + yj +zk$ i'm supposed to use the solution from finding the parametrization $F(x,y,z) = 2cos(t)i+2sin(t)j+2sin(t)+3k$ right?

Comment: Yes, but I would rather put the last component into a bracket, like $F(x,y,z) = 2\cos(t)i+2\sin(t)j+(2\sin(t)+3)k$

Comment: I wish you that your algebraic vision is associated with a geometric vision of the scene : when you cut a cylinder by a slant plane (slant, here = not orthogonal to the axis of the cylinder), you get an ellipse...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for pointing this out.  Sorry for such error.  I'm going to correct it.